# Python: Why can't I do arithmetic operations on a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my homework question. Why can't I perform arithmetic operations on a set. For example:
`{a+b} * c` returns an error. Why?

When we try to do [a+b]*c, it returns a list. For instance: [4+5]*6 returns [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]. But the same is not the result for the set. Why?

Sorry I am quite new to Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By definition, sets cannot contain duplicates.

Comment: What do you think ` {4+5}*6 ` could mean. Remember that `{9,9,9,9,9,9}` is the same as `{9}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sets are not sequences. For sequences `+` is the concatenation operator, and sets don't implement concatenation, similarly, `*` is the repetition operator, basically, it repeatedly concatenates. Again, this isn't a defined operation for sets. Sequences are essentially ordered collections of objects that can be indexed with `int` objects and can contain duplicates. Examples of sequences are `tuple`, `list`, `str`, and `range` objects sets are unordered collections that cannot be indexed at all, and do not contain duplicates.

*However* sets do define things like *intersection*, *union*, and *difference* operations using the `^`, `|`, and `-` operators, respectively:

```
>>> {1, 2} ^ {1, 3}
{2, 3}
>>> {1, 2} | {1, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
>>> {1, 2} - {1, 3}
{2}
```

So the answer is that `set` objects do not use `+` and `*` because those operators are conventionally used for operations that do not make sense for the set data type.

So ask yourself, *what would you expect* `+` and `*` to do with set objects?

Comment: Ask myself? Well then :) – set * set = intersect, set + set = union. What else? – | (or) for union and & (and) for internet is tech terminology, not semantic.

Comment: @flaschbier well, of course, it relies on a familiarity with the convention in programming particularly in languages influenced by C. There is a clear analogy between bitwise operations and set operations.

Comment: @flaschbier and in Python there is an idea of [sequence-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), and we reserve the `+` and `*` operators for particular types of operations on those sequence type collections, whereas set-like collections use another choice of operators. But there is no reason in principle why they couldn't use the same operators.

Answer (score 1):

`[a+b]*c` returns a list, not a set. Because elements in a set is unique, so you cannot use '*' to initial a set.